# LINQ Select on string results in char

Tags: linq, select

I have an array of objects with which I'm using LINQ to construct an object for a webservice, the problem I'm having is that where some of the data needs to be truncated under one of the selected values the select parameter is using a char instead of a string:

```
WebService.ORDER_WRITE_REQUEST WebServiceObject = new WebService.ORDER_WRITE_REQUEST();

WebServiceObject.ITEMS = array.Item
.Select(x => new WebService.ITEMS
{
Value1 = x.Units.UnitName.Where(x => x != null).Select(x => x.Length > 5 ? x.Substring(0, 5) : w);
}
```

The 'UnitName' value is a String but the parameter x ends up converting it to a char so I'm actually unable to use the substring method in the linq query.

I see the select is expecting it to be a char, but I'm sure i've done this before without issue. Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`UnitName` is a string which implements `IEnumerable<char>`, you're enumerating all chars.

You want this:

```
...
Value1 = x.Units
    .Where(x => x.UnitName != null)
    .Select(x => x.UnitName.Length > 5 ? x.UnitName.Substring(0, 5) : w);
...
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, but there's a problem with that where x as the where + select parameters give a new meaning to the x under Value1. Good in theory buit I'm not sure it can work this way, any ideas?